# page not found for single-type.php file

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error

i have created custom post type 'event' to display in single page named single-event.php file but it provides me 404 error. how i can solve this problem even i used

> flush_rewrite_rules();

please provide some idea.......

```
function custom_event() {
$labels = array( 
   'name' => _x('Event', 'post type general name'),
   'singular_name' => _x('Event', 'post type singular name'),
   'add_new' => _x('Add Event', 'Content'),
   'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event'),
   'edit_item' => __('Edit Event'),
   'new_item' => __('New Content'),
   'view_item' => __('View Event'),
   'search_items' => __('Search Content'),
   'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'), 
   'parent_item_colon' => '',
   'menu_name' => __('Event')
);

 $args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui' => true, 
'show_in_menu' => true, 
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'has_archive' => true, 
'hierarchical' => false,
'menu_position' => 20,
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor')
 );

flush_rewrite_rules();
register_post_type('event', $args);
}
  //$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
  //add_action('admin_init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');
    add_action ('init', 'custom_event');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [this](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress) tutorial for creating the custom post type.

Here is the working code as per your requirement:

```
function create_post_type_event() {

    //Create custom post type for event

    $labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Event', 'post type general name'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Event', 'post type singular name'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'event'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Event'),
            'new_item' => __('New Event'),
            'all_items' => __('All Events'),
            'view_item' => __('View Event'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Event'),
            'not_found' =>  __('No event found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No event found in Trash'),
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => __('Event')

    );
    $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => TRUE,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields' )
    );
    register_post_type('event',$args);

    flush_rewrite_rules();          // Flush the rewrite rules and re-create the above for custom post types

}

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_event' );
```

After creating this `cpt` you can create a `single-event.php` file in your active theme's directory and it should work with no trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Place flush_rewrite_rules(); after the register call.
Also, Try flushing your rewrite rules through WP Admin, by visiting WP Admin -> Settings -> Permalink -> Press Save button.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event' )` instead of `'rewrite' => true`.

Also, you shouldn't use `flush_rewrite_rules()` like this. It will run unnecessarily each time. You could make a plugin to define the custom post type and flush the rewrite rules using `register_activation_hook`.